# Javascript - how to correctly verify form data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a form with a few text inputs and also with one file-type input, in which I attempt to verify, if the selected file is PDF. I am doing that this way:

```
$("#myform").bind("submit", function() {
    var ext = $('#file_input').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
    if($.inArray(ext, ['pdf']) == -1) {
        alert('ERROR!');
    }
});
```

But in the part of code above is one lack - if all inputs except the file-input (lets sat the file is DOC) are valid (=> file-input is not valid) and I click on the SUBMIT button, then is displayed alert message **ERROR!**, but the form is sent.

How can I "stop" sending the form, if the file type is not valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#myform").bind("submit", function(e) {
    var ext = $('#file_input').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
    if($.inArray(ext, ['pdf']) == -1) {
      e.preventDefault(); //Prevents the default action which is form submit
      alert('ERROR!');
    }
});
```

Comment: @JamWaffles I have already added the comment next to the line I have added. If that is not sufficient enough I can add more explanation

Comment: More explanation would be better, as would a link to the documentation. It's always a good idea to show the OP _why_ your answer works; it helps them learn.

Comment: @JamWaffles I agree with you on the explanation, but when needed. The change here looks feels self explanatory (in my view).

Answer (score 2):

You can shorten the code by doing this:

```
if (!(/\.pdf$/i).test($('#file_input').val())) {
  // not valid, do what you like here
  // return false to prevent submit
  return false;
```

The form is prevented from submitting by returning false; preventDefault on the form submit event is not working in IE 7/8, return false does the job.

Comment: @JamWaffles Please read the answer before commenting. It solves the problem by returning false, and makes the code shorter and more concise.

Comment: Sorry, now I feel like a fool. My apologies.

Answer (score 2):

In a jQuery callback function bound to an event you have two options.

You can pass a reference to the event to the anonymous function and call `e.preventDefault()`:

```
$('#myform').bind('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Your code
});
```

`e.preventDefault()` prevents the default functionality (in this case, submitting the form).

Or you can `return false` to both prevent the default functionality **and** prevent the event from bubbling; the same as calling `e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 ways:

1. Keep your code as it is and add `return false`:

   ```
   $("#myform").bind("submit", function() {
   var ext = $('#file_input').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
   if($.inArray(ext, ['pdf']) == -1) {
       alert('ERROR!');
       return false;
   }
   });
   ```
2. change the function signature to accept the event and use the preventDefault():

   ```
    $("#myform").bind("submit", function(e) {       
   var ext = $('#file_input').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
   if($.inArray(ext, ['pdf']) == -1) {         
     alert('ERROR!');
     e.preventDefault();
   }
   });
   ```